# Trying to read a file in UEFI but code stops working after deleting an unused line of code

Tags: c, operating-system, bootloader, uefi

I'm trying to open and read a file in UEFI but after I delete the line `char c = *buf;` it stops working? The lines below that will not get executed for some reason?

Im so confused because that line is not even doing anything useful??

```
#include <efi.h>
#include <efilib.h>


EFI_FILE_HANDLE getvolume(EFI_HANDLE);
EFI_FILE_HANDLE openfile(EFI_FILE_HANDLE, CHAR16*);

EFI_STATUS efi_main(EFI_HANDLE IH, EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE *ST) {
    InitializeLib(IH, ST);
    uefi_call_wrapper(ST->ConOut->Reset, 2, ST->ConOut, 1);
    Print(L"Hello, world!\n");
    EFI_FILE_HANDLE vol = getvolume(IH);
    EFI_FILE_HANDLE filehandle = openfile(vol, L"kernel.elf");
    int bufsz = 10000;
    char buf[bufsz];
    EFI_STATUS status = uefi_call_wrapper(filehandle->Read, 3, filehandle, &bufsz, buf);

    char c = *buf; // if i delete this the status will not get printed
    Print(L"%d\n", status);

    for (;;);
}


EFI_FILE_HANDLE openfile(EFI_FILE_HANDLE vol, CHAR16* filename) {
    EFI_FILE_HANDLE temphandle;
    EFI_STATUS status = uefi_call_wrapper(vol->Open, 5, vol, &temphandle, filename, EFI_FILE_MODE_READ, 0);
    if (status != 0)
        return 0;
    return temphandle;
}

EFI_FILE_HANDLE getvolume(EFI_HANDLE IH) {
    EFI_LOADED_IMAGE *limg = 0;
    EFI_GUID lipGuid = EFI_LOADED_IMAGE_PROTOCOL_GUID;
    EFI_FILE_IO_INTERFACE *IOVolume;
    EFI_GUID fsGuid = EFI_SIMPLE_FILE_SYSTEM_PROTOCOL_GUID;
    EFI_FILE_HANDLE Volume;
    uefi_call_wrapper(BS->HandleProtocol, 3, IH, &lipGuid, (void**)&limg);
    uefi_call_wrapper(BS->HandleProtocol, 3, limg->DeviceHandle, &fsGuid, (void*)&IOVolume);
    uefi_call_wrapper(IOVolume->OpenVolume, 2, IOVolume, &Volume);
    return Volume;
}
```

Comment: 'buf' is not a pointer, so you cannot dereference it.

Comment: '&buf' would make a bit more sense, but not by much.

Comment: what are you talking about? Array variable decays into a pointer in an expression

Comment: Compare the resulting assembly code to see what the compiler really builds.

Comment: @Martin, *buf is completely correct.

Comment: How much memory does 'char buf[bufsz];' allocate on the stack?  It may not be what you think it is.  If you change the line to 'char buf[10000];' does it now work as expected?